# expect - how to discard the buffer if expected string is not found

Tags: expect

I need to spawn a script that produces lots of output which makes the regex matching of the output slow.  Also the buffer fills quickly even when I use quite a large `match_max` value.

I would like to check the output for a particular string.  If the string does not exist, I would like to discard the output read so far.

I have tried using default matches, globs and negative regexes to catch the unwanted strings, but could not get this working.

How can this be done with expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 'seems' to work (more testing is required):

```
set success_string "\[INFO\] Started Jetty\r\n"

spawn "/usr/bin/mvn" "-pl" ":cloud-client-ui" "jetty:run"
expect {
  -re "(\[^\r]*\)\r\n" 
  {
    set current_line $expect_out(buffer)
    if { [string equal "$current_line" "$success_string"] } {
       puts "exiting with matched string $current_line"
       exit 0
    } else { 
       puts "discarding $current_line"
       exp_continue 
    }
  }
  eof { puts "eof"; exit 1; }
  timeout { puts "timeout"; exit 1; }
}
```